# Import table from another latex file

Tags: latex

Is it possible to have a `tables.tex` file and then import specific tables into other files?

Comment: Have a look at the `catchfilebetweentags` package

Comment: Have a look at the `input` command [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Management_in_a_large_project).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is!

Copy the following example code into a file called `main.tex` (or any other name):

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Some text.

\input{tables.tex}

Some other text.

\end{document}
```

Then copy the following code for *one* table into a file called `tables.tex`:

```latex
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|l|c|r|}
    \hline
    a & b & c\\
    \hline
    d & e & f\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Save them both in the same folder and compile the first one.

If your `tables.tex` file is in a subfolder or different folder, edit the path in the code accordingly like `\input{subfolder/tables.tex}` or `\input{../other_folder/tables.tex}`.

If you need two or more different tables in different sections of the same document, then you need to input more files, e.g. `table1.tex`, `table2.tex`, ecc.

Also very important: [`input` command vs. `include` command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246/49683).

Comment: So there isn't a way to have all my tables in a ```tables.tex``` file and input specific ones?

Comment: @LegendWK yes there is: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/catchfilebetweentags